# why the video is rotated by 90 degrees at PC?

Tags: android

Shooting `video` with `MediaRecorder` class is good, shooting results in the phone, it was also ok, but uploaded to the computer to see the `video`,but it is rotated by `90` degrees. How to solve?

Comment: Some video players considers the orientation hint when playing a video. Other players don't. Just try to play this video in your PC with Windows Media Player, Quick Time and Real Player and see the differences.
Probably the problem is not your code, but the video player you are using to view your video.

Comment: On what platform ? what pc ? What Media Recorder ? Is this even a programming related question ?? Pls provide more details.

Comment: I have try setOrientationHint(90); setOrientationHint(180); setOrientationHint(270); The video is ok at phone. But uploaded to the computer to see the video, it is rotated by 90 degrees too.
mediarecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mediarecorder.setCamera(camera);
            ...

Answer (score 0):

Usually, some vendor like **samsung** or **sony**... make their devices to record video in `landscape` mode. Maybe you record video in vertical orientation and review video after that on the laptop should be rotated by 90 degrees. I faced this issue in my project and the way to solve that is: detect the orientation by use the phone's sensor, after that use `setOrientationHint(int degrees)` method in `MediaRecorder` class to have a suitable orientation .